# Change between MediaElement and BackgroundAudioPlayer

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, background-audio

For now I am using `MediaElement` for Playing video in my app with this code:

```
mediaElement1.Source = new Uri(fileurl);
mediaElement1.Play();
```

and I want to add the possible of when the user go to Background and keep play the audio(No need the video), So I want to use `BackgroundAudioPlayer` for this. And I want to know if it is possible to use the two of them or how I can mix between them.

Comment: In order to accomplish this you would need to have an audio file playing in a background agent along with the video playing in a MediaElement. There is no guarantee that they would be synced.